# Shogun Installation on Windows

Tags: windows, shogun

The latest version of Shogun 4.0.0 (Released Jan, 2015) is reported to allow Windows installation as well. I am using Windows 10. Can anyone guide me in case they have done it?

*(My question may seem quite blank but I have put in a lot of effort and research before coming here. Unfortunately, I have zero success so far)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4.0.0 definitely had no Windows support, only via cygwin.

I've been working on this during the weekend and already have an almost complete native Windows port of shogun in the feature/windows branch of the official git repository: https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/tree/feature/windows

around September we will release 5.0.0, which will include this as well.

Comment: Thanks Viktor. Looking forward to it for using as the tool for my upcoming ML course